# Xamarin forms: Top stacklayout is not visible in UI when keyboard is on

Tags: xamarin.forms, stacklayout

**My Xaml:**

```
<StackLayout
   Orientation="Vertical">

   <StackLayout
      Orientation="Horizontal"> 
      //Group labels and back arrow
   </StackLayout>

   <ListView>
      //Message list
   </ListView>

   <Grid>
   //Plus symbol,Editor and send icon
   </Grid>

</StackLayout>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Issue:**

In normal screen there is a bar on the top(red circled). When click the editor on the bottom top bar is hiding. I need the top bar always on top. **This issue is only in IOS part, in android this feature is working fine. How can I fix this issue?**

Comment: Did you set VerticalOption to FillAndExpand of Top StackLayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the picture in the question my soft keyboard always touching the Editor. So I added a custom renderer for my Editor to solve that issue. **After adding that custom renderer the top bar is always sticking on the top of the page.**

I used the following custom renderer to solve the keyboard overlapping issue:

```
using System;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using HBIClientFacingApp;
using HBIClientFacingApp.iOS;

[assembly:ExportRenderer( typeof(CustomEditor), typeof(CustomEditorRenderer))]
namespace YourNameSpace.iOS
{
    public class CustomEditorRenderer: EditorRenderer
    {
        public ChatEntryRenderer()
        {   
            UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveWillShow ((sender, args) => {

            if (Element != null)
            {
                Element.Margin = new Thickness(0,0,0, args.FrameEnd.Height); //push the entry up to keyboard height when keyboard is activated
            }
        });

        UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveWillHide ((sender, args) => {

            if (Element != null)
            {
                   Element.Margin = new Thickness(0); //set the margins to zero when keyboard is dismissed
            }

        }); 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its an iOS feature that the UI is adjusted upwards. You can shrink (or keep) the view via a custom renderer.

Check [this great explanation](https://xamarinhelp.com/accommodate-on-screen-keyboard-xamarin-forms/).

And also [this peace of code](https://github.com/adamped/SoftInput/blob/master/SoftInput/SoftInput.iOS/Render/KeyboardRender.cs) for a keyboard custom renderer on iOS.

Comment: I have used another custom renderer to solve this issue, thanks for your time and advice. Also updated the right answer here.